# PowerShell Help - hide errors [Newbie]

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to locate all the sites that a user has access to in Sharepoint, for this I am running the script below, however, I know that sites that the user does not have access to in some sites and it will return an error.

Is there any way to hide the errors while the code is running? I tried a few option but none worked.

```
$arr = @(); get-sposite | %{ $user = get-spouser -site $_ -loginName "user@email.com" -ErrorVariable 'MyError'; if($user.Groups.Count -gt 0){ $arr += new-object psobject -property @{site=$_.url; groups=$user.Groups} } }; $arr
```

Error

```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-SPOUser], ServerUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.GetSPOUser
 
get-spouser : Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this feature.
No linha:5 caractere:13
+     $user = get-spouser -site $_ -loginName "name.user@email.com";
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-SPOUser], ServerUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.GetSPOUser
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for the parameter `-ErrorAction` with argument `SilentlyContinue`. There are also several improvements you could make to your code.

```
$arr = get-sposite | Foreach-Object{
    $user = get-spouser -site $_ -loginName "user@email.com" -ErrorVariable 'MyError' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($user.Groups.Count -gt 0){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            site   = $_.url
            groups = $user.Groups
        }
    }
}

$arr
```

**EDIT**

The cmdlet `Get-SPOuser` doesn't appear to behave as it should and honor the `-ErrorAction` parameter. Here is a work around.

```
$currentEA = $ErrorActionPreference

$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$arr = get-sposite | Foreach-Object{
    $user = get-spouser -site $_ -loginName "user@email.com" -ErrorVariable 'MyError'
    if($user.Groups.Count -gt 0){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            site   = $_.url
            groups = $user.Groups
        }
    }
}

$ErrorActionPreference = $currentEA

$arr
```

Comment: didn't work, it's still returning the error :( 

I honestly don't know anything about powershell but I'm trying to find a way to get this information.

Comment: Just tested and you are correct. It seems the cmdlet doesn't obey the parameter. I've updated the post with a work around.

Comment: You can use file redirection to suppress the error, if it's an error. Use `2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

@Gabriel Franco,

You use `try {...} catch {...}` when you want to handle errors. If you want to ignore them, you should set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue" (or "SilentlyContinue")` as @Doug Maurer suggested.

you'd put that instruction in the `try {...} catch {...}` block, not the entire loop, e.g.:

```
$arr = get-sposite | Foreach-Object{
    try{
        $user = get-spouser -site $_ -loginName "user@email.com" -ErrorVariable 'MyError'
        if($user.Groups.Count -gt 0){
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                site   = $_.url
                groups = $user.Groups
            }
        }
    }catch{
        LogWrite ($Error[0].Exception)
    }      
}
```

BR